# How to Use Tr:nth-of-type(even) With a Class?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors, tablerow

I have tried to use this code:

```
.whitetr tr:nth-of-type(even) {
background-color:#d9d9d9;
border:1px solid #d9d9d9;
color:black;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

I have two top table rows that have different classes that I would like to not be affected by the top code (which is why I am trying to use a class).

If I just use:

```
tr:nth-of-type(even) {
background-color:#d9d9d9;
border:1px solid #d9d9d9;
color:black;
}
```

, it works, but it changes my top two table rows.

Here is my table code:

```
<table><tr id="header" bgcolor="#7b354e"><td colspan="8"><div id="desc">UNITS - LOT</div><div id="titlee"><a href="dp">Gd</a></div><div id="time"><?php  $datae1 = date('F j, Y \a\\t h:i a'); echo "".$datae1."";?></div></td></tr><tr><td id="ti1">CUSTOMER</td><td id="ti2">MAKE</td><td id="ti3">MODEL</td><td id="ti4">UNIT</td><td id="ti8">WO</td><td id="ti5">DATE of ARRIVAL</td><td id="ti6">NOTES - work to be performed</td><td id="ti7">STATUS</td></tr>
<?php $num_results = mssql_num_rows($objQuery);
for($i=$Page_Start;$i<$Page_End;$i++)  
{  
    $num_found = $i + 1;
    $row = mssql_fetch_assoc($objQuery);
?><tr class="whitetr"><td class="td1"><?=mssql_result($objQuery,$i,"customer");?></td><td class="td2"><?=mssql_result($objQuery,$i,"make");?></td><td class="td3"><?=mssql_result($objQuery,$i,"model");?></td><td class="td4"><?=mssql_result($objQuery,$i,"unit");?></td><td class="td8"><?=mssql_result($objQuery,$i,"wo");?></td><td class="td5"><?=mssql_result($objQuery,$i,"date");?></td><td class="td6"><?=mssql_result($objQuery,$i,"notes");?></td><td class="td7"><?=mssql_result($objQuery,$i,"status");?></td></tr><?php }?>
</table>
```

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huulktya/SzfW6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your class is applied to the `tr` itself you might be after this:

```
tr.whitetr:nth-of-type(even) {
...
```